# Getter for timeout class returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have this class. It's supposed to create a timeout that allows me to see how far it is done. However, it returns nothing. Does anyone know what's wrong? This returns an error in the browser. It only works in node.js

```
class Timeout extends setTimeout{
    constructor(){
        super(...arguments)
        this.start = new Date()
    }
    get timeLeft(){
        console.log('getting time left')
        return this.start
    }
}
console.log(new Timeout().timeLeft)
```

Comment: `extends setTimeout` :/

Comment: `extends setTimeout` what are you trying to do with this? `setTimeout` isn't a constructor or a class

Comment: @James It works for me in node.js. It doesn't work in the browser though. I think `setTimeout` can be converted to a class in node.js. According to node.js it is a constructor or at least close enough to one.

Comment: @ElectroxMortem I'm sure it will work, you can extend any function.... it's just a really bad approach for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Do you have a better approach....?

Comment: @ElectroxMortem don't extend `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any reason to extend from setTimeout. setTimeout is not a class or a constructor. Node apparently lets you get away with it, but the browser does not. Instead, how about this:

```js
class Timeout {
  constructor(...args) {
    setTimeout(...args);
    this.start = new Date();
  }
  get timeLeft(){
    console.log('getting time left');
    return this.start;
  }
}
new Timeout(() => console.log('timer went off'), 1000).timeLeft
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `get` method definition is not working because the `setTimeout` definition is not allowing it. I think you would be better using composition instead of extension:

```
class Timeout {
  constructor() {
    this.timeout = new setTimeout(...arguments);
    this.start = new Date();
  }
  // ...
```

In this way `"getting time left"` is logged along the `this.start` time.

Answer (score 0):

So you have wrote getter for field called `timeLeft`, but you named your field `start`.
Also you can extend only class, but you've tried to extend function which is incorrect.

Different browsers behave differently and Node.js is yet another environment that runs JS.
This is why we use transpilation process to unify JS behaviour across different environment.